# don't want to submit with prefilled value textarea; I have a required validation for text area but is not caught either

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have a textarea which is populated with text and if you click on it but type nothing when you leave the default pre-filled text will be populated again; I don't want to allow submission with pre-filled text for my form; how can I handle this issue?

My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("textarea").val("Please enter your email content here...");
   $("textarea").focusout(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            $(this).val("Please enter your email content here...");
        }
    });
    $("textarea").focus(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "Please enter your email content here...") {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not use the HTML5 placeholder attribute instead?

Comment: why don't you use [placehodler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder) attribute instead of the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simply doing:

```
<textarea placeholder="Default text here"></textarea>
```

Otherwise, if you need support for *oldies* than try to store your def. text into a variable and on submit check for the submitted value is actually your Default.

http://jsbin.com/unuqes/1/edit

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var $txtA = $("textarea");
  var emailDef = "Please enter your email content here...";

  $txtA.val(emailDef);

  $txtA.focusout(function() {
     if ($.trim(this.value) === "") {
         this.value = emailDef;
     }
  });

  $txtA.focus(function() {
     if( this.value === emailDef ) {
         this.value="";
     }
  });

  $('form').submit(function(){
    var txtAval = $txtA[0].value;
    if(txtAval==emailDef || !$.trim(txtAval)){
      alert("Missing your email!");
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: note: the above solution will not work in < IE10 and Opera Mini

Comment: thus if its important information that is mentioned in the textarea, please have some sort of graceful degradation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_placeholder.asp) to show the message?

I don't see why you use jQuery for this